# Update Product Attribute with WooCommerce.NET / Rest API in C#

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, rest

I use WooCommerce Rest API in c#
I have no problem with add the product with(Attribute/Variant/Image/Category) in WooCommerce with C#

I use the following code to get the product code and I can add (Attribute/Variant/Image/Category)

```
RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("https://examople.com/wp-json/wc/v3", "ck_021ac*************5d20249", "cs_24c387************659ee3d588cf", false);
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

        string SKU = "2222";
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        Dictionary<string, string> pDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pDic.Add("sku", SKU);

        int productIDfromSKU = 0;
        //int productNfromSKU = 0;
        products = await wc.Product.GetAll(pDic);

        if (products.Count > 0)
        {
            productIDfromSKU = Convert.ToInt32(products[0].id);
            //productNfromSKU = Convert.ToInt32(products[0].price);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(productIDfromSKU.ToString());
```

But for the update (Attribute/Variant/Image/Category) there is no code or sample anywhere

Answer (score 0):

For Variation update:  I tried and this is working.

```
Variation v = new Variation()
              {
                  id = 25501
                  stock_status = "outofstock"
              };

var res = await wc.Product.Variations.Update(25496,v,25496); // set productid as parent id
```

Same way you can do for Attribute/Image/Category update.

Still i m looking for assigning brand for a product.